# Django: making user email unique=True is causing a problem

Tags: django

I made email field unique in the user model because I don't want users sharing same email.
But now the problem is that when I created the first user without email address and then tried to create a second user without email address, I got error message about user with email already existing whereas there's no user yet with email address.

I edited the first user and added an email address before I could successfully create a second user without email address. Please what am I doing wrong? I want to be able to create several users without email address.

Comment: Use [`field options`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#field-options), `null` and `blank`.

Comment: If you set unique=True in model fields, by default you can't add multiple entries with blank files because two blank values are not unique, on thing you can do is remove that unique constraint and check for uniqueness manually on saving each user instance by overriding the save method of User model..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom uniqe = True

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if not mymodel.object.filter(email=self.email) or self.email =="" or (not self._state.adding and len(mymodel.object.filter(email=self.email))<=1 and mymodel.object.filter(pk=self.pk)[0].email == self.email):
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
    else:
        raise ValueError()
```